# Populate AtlasConversationsRecyclerView with custom HTTP response

Tags: layer, atlas

I am working on an Android app, using Layer Atlas for the conversations section. Right now I am trying to populate the conversations list (AtlasConversationsRecyclerView) with my own query:

```
private AtlasConversationsRecyclerView mConversationsList;
.
.
.
HTTPRequestManager.fetchConversations(
  new HTTPRequestManager.VolleyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
      JSONArray jsonArray = Base.toJSONResponse(response);
      JSONArray sortedJsonArray = Base.sortJSONArray(jsonArray, Base.CREATE_TIMESTAMP);
    // mConversationsAdapter.setData(sortedJsonArray);
  }
}, Base.mChannelId);
```

What I normally do to populate an ordinary RecyclerView is write an adapter for it, specifically a setData() method that solves the query-view integration (mConversationsAdapter.setData(..)). This time, I have the query response, but I don't understand how to use it to populate the AtlasConversationsRecyclerView, which has its own adapter.

The code that comes next:

```
// Atlas methods
mConversationsList.init(getLayerClient(), getPicasso())
.setInitialHistoricMessagesToFetch(20)
.setOnConversationClickListener(new AtlasConversationsAdapter.OnConversationClickListener() {...}
```

This is what I found on the reference files, but I am missing the query-adapter integration part.

Could you please give me some advice?

Thank you,
Michelle